# Limit WsClient download size

Tags: scala, playframework, ws-client

I'm performing an url parsing with `WsClient`. However, I don't want to parse a remote resource that contain large amount of data (for example, a url that points to a video).

Is there a built-in option to set the remote content limit in `WsClient`?

Is it possible to do it **without** Akka Stream? The difficulty with using stream is that it provides a `ByteString`, so there is a content encoding headache (utf8, cp1251, etc).

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: Play Framework 2.5 with scala